# JS and querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

A `querySelectorAll` question, most likely a silly one, but I don't see the solution.

I have something like the following

```
<div id="main_0"> ... </div>
<div id="main_1"> ... </div>
<div id="main_1_minor"> ... </div>
<div id="main_2"> ... </div>
<div id="main_2_minor"> ... </div>
              .
              .
```

I wish to select all and only those div's without `minor`.

I tried

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^main_\\d');
var elSelected = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^=main_]');
elSelected.filter(elt => pattern.test(elt.id)));
```

but clearly it is not enough.  I am not sure how to formulate by RegEx that the id value has to terminate with a digit. I tried something like `RegExp('^main_\\d$');` but I did not get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter won't work for NodeList, cast to array first. Also if you already selected all `main` divs the simplest regex would be enough.

```js
var pattern = new RegExp(/\d+$/);
var elSelected = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div[id^=main_]'));

elSelected.filter(elt => pattern.test(elt.id)).forEach(function(elt){
 elt.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
});
```

```html
<div id="main_0">main_0</div>
<div id="main_1">main_1</div>
<div id="main_1_minor">main_1_minor</div>
<div id="main_2">main_2</div>
<div id="main_0_minor">main_0_minor</div>
```

Comment: I only added forEach to color the output to your code. It works in a snippet though.

Comment: it seems it works if the <script> portion is below the div's. Is that so?

Comment: Yes, the recommended way is to put `<script>`'s at the bottom of the page before the `</body>`. If you manipulating DOM elements you need to do either this or wait till the page's loaded.

Comment: @scroder4 yes of course, too much used to JQuery. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `:not()` selector with the "attribute ends with" selector.

```
"div:not([id$=minor])"
```

If it should also verify that the `id` starts with `main_`, then you can add that too as you show in your question.

```
"div[id^=main_]:not([id$=minor])"
```

So this says *"select all `div` elements where the `id` starts with `main_` and does not end with `minor`"*.

If `minor` is not necessarily at the end, then you can use `id*=minor` for "contains" instead.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div[id^=main_]:not([id$=minor])")
  .forEach(el => el.style.color = "red");
```

```html
<div id="main_0"> main </div>
<div id="main_1"> main </div>
<div id="main_1_minor"> main ends with minor </div>
<div id="main_2"> main </div>
<div id="main_2_minor"> main ends with minor </div>
```

Comment: remind myself how I do say _does not end with anything else_

Comment: @mario: That would be the same as saying "ends with ...". In other words, does not end with anything else besides "foo", means it must end with "foo", so `[id$=foo]`

Comment: @mario, if you design the html, you can add specific class for the divs, then just querySelectorAll('.specific-class-name'), it will make your life easier.

Comment: @Sphinx, actually, I don't.